# clang-format for one-liner namespaces

Tags: clang-format

Is there any way of collapsing short namespaces such as;

```
namespace Internal {
   class StatesEditorImageProvider;
}
```

into this;

```
namespace Internal { class StatesEditorImageProvider; }
```

with clang-format?

I've tried `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` with `Always` and `true` but it doesn't work for namespaces.